# Can you use && with a ternary operator in HTML

Tags: html, angular7, ternary

I'm trying to see if I can use an && condition in a ternary expression in my application.  Here is an example from my HTML file:

```
"step-bar {{(ifBooleanOneIsTrue && ifBooleanTwoIsTrue )  ? 'completed' : 
  'incompleted'}}"
```

I want the 'completed' class to be returned, only if both booleans have the value of true.  Is this possible or are there some changes I can make with this code?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, you can use `&&` in a ternary. I suspect your problem may come from trying to use interpolation inside quotation marks, but it's hard to say without more context.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a variable had an extra character.  Spent the last hour banging my head against the wall when it was just syntax.  Thanks everyone, false alarm :(